# PHP Serialization and deserialization concept

Tags: php

I tried this serialization code but the value gets printed is not what I expected.It has to display "You are objectifying me" when last display function is called but it is not doing so.Can anyone point what is the error in the code.

```
 <?php
            class ClassTOSerialize
            {
                public $storedStatement="data";
                public function _constructor($statement)
                {
                    $this->storedStatement=$statement;
                }
                public function display()
                {
                    print($this->storedStatement."<BR>");
                }

            }
            $instance1=new ClassTOSerialize("You are objectifying me!");
            $instance1->display();
            $serialization=serialize($instance1);
            $instance2=  unserialize($serialization);
            $instance2->display();


            /*
             * 
             */
            ?>
```

Comment: Just a note for a common pitfall when doing this... Keep in mind that [Object Serialization](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.serialization.php) does not retain it's methods when serialized -- so if you decided to store this externally for later use you'll need to make sure the class is already included in the document before calling any class methods after unserialization.

Answer (score 2):

It has zero to do with serialisation. A class' constructor is called `__construct`, not `_constructor`. So yours never gets executed and the statement is never stored anywhere. That's all.

Answer (score -2):

I found it out instead of using the keyword constructor just keep the function name as

```
 public function ClassToSerialize()
    {
      $this->storedStatement=$statement;
    }
```

Then you are objectifying me will be printed

Comment: This is old-fashioned way in PHP.